# .bash_aliases causing troubles to .bashrc

Tags: bash

I have got 2 users on my computer

/home/achille 
and 
/home/bozo

When logged under achille, I run

```
source .bashrc
```

it runs ok; no error message.

I create .bash_aliases, re-do the same command:

and have got the following error message:

```
bash: .bashrc: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash: .bashrc: line 34: `if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then'
```

then

mv .bash_aliases bash_aliases

then

source .bashrc

I have got the same error message.

Now I log as bozo and go to its ~ directory and run the same command. Everything run smoothly (there is no error msg).

```
diff /home/achille/.bashrc /home/bozo/.bashrc
```

and there are no differences at all.

I re-log as achille and run

source .bashrc

no error message.

as soon as I put a new .bash_aliases

I have got (a new!!) error message:

bash: .bashrc: line 111: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash: .bashrc: line 111:`if ! shopt -oq posix; then'

.bashrc and .bash_aliases belong to achille achille

Here is the .bash_aliases content:

```
alias netd='service network-manager stop && ifconfig wlp2s0 down && macchanger -A wlp2s0'
alias netu='ifconfig wlp2s0 up && service network-manager start'
alias if='ifconfig wlp2s0' 
alias delc='rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.sqlite && rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js && rm -r ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/*'
```

Thanx folks.

Comment: `alias if=...` seriously?

Comment: Another reason to use shell functions instead of aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aliased `if` to `ifconfig wlp2s0`, therefore you can't use it in conditionals anymore.

```
$ alias if=echo
$ if [ 1 == 1 ] ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
$ if Hello world
Hello world
```